# What is the best way to interact with a smart contract from Django?

Tags: nft, brownie, mint, django

I developed a smart contract (ERC721) for minting NFTs.
I want to mint an NFT on a Django server when some specific event occurs. I do know how to mint them using Brownie framework but I don't know how to do it in Django.
Is it a good idea to use both Django and Brownie or what other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Web3.py. It's like Web3.js but for Python, so you could use it in your Django backend.

This should be a comment but I don't have 50 reputation yet